# RecordEditor using imports that does not exist

Tags: cobol, jrecord

I'm using Record editor to generate my classes, but I have two imports that doesn't work

```
import net.sf.JRecord.def.IO.builders.ICobolIOBuilder;
```

and

```
JRecordInterface1.COBOL
```

I'm using JRecord 0.80 and I can't upgrade to 0.90, is there any way to generate the code from Record Editor to JRecord 0.80? I think this may be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely correct, `JRecordInterface1.COBOL` was introduced in version 0.8?.?, so is not available in earlier versions of JRecord. It would be useful to know the actual version of JRecord being used.

You **might** be able to replace `JRecordInterface1.COBOL` with `CobolIoProvider.getInstance()` in the generated code. Again **CobolIoProvider.getInstance()** might not be available depending on there version version of *JRecord* being used.

### External Templates

You can use an external templates in the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) instead of the supplied templates.

[image: Template Field]

#### JRecord 0.80 Template

There is a `JRecord 0.80` Template **StandardTemplate_For_jrecord_0.80_V01.00.zip**
at [JRecord Templates](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/files/jrecord_CodeGen/CodeGen_Examples/)

#### Using JRecord 0.80 Template

In the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/)

- Select **Generate >>> Java JRecord Code for Cobol**
- Enter the Cobol Copybook and optionally the Cobol Data file. Also *Select*
  the `Drop copybook names from field names` option.
  [image]
- Enter the **StandardTemplate_JRecord_080** directory in the *template directory* field.
  [image]
- Hit the next button to generate the template.

### Setting the JRecord Version

There is an option on the Generate screen to set the *JRecord* version, the *earliest* version supported is **81.5**. Not much use to you but may be useful for others.

[image: JRecord Version field]

Comment: thanks for the workaround, we're going to try with this

Comment: Hopefully it will work. I will update the answer further

Comment: @JoseCarlosPB updated JRecord answer to reference JRecord 0.80 Template